# How to read a whole folder's files into one RDD map in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I use binaryFiles to read files from HDFS, but one map only has one file.

```
sparkContext.binaryFiles("hdfs://name/a/b/id-*.zzz").map(x=>{})
```

In the map phase, I can only deal with one file. Can I set two or more files in one map, and deal with them parallel?

Answer (score 0):

```
def wholeTextFiles(
  path: String,
  minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[(String, String)] = withScope
```

Returns paired RDD, where key is the File and value is Content

Comment: binaryFiles also return the RDD<filename, fileContent>